# How to output file above public folder Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have debian machine and my site is in /var/www/laravel-site/ folder.
In laravel-site folder i have FILES and PUBLIC folders. How can i output file to FILES folder to protect the file from web reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `base_path()` will help

Simple usage example:

```
<?php
    $file = base_path('FILES').'/people.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= "John Smith\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

`function base_path($path = '')` is a Laravel helper function. It gets the path to the base of the install:

```
function base_path($path = '')
{
     return app()->basePath().($path ? '/'.$path : $path);
}
```

So, to get your `/var/www/laravel-site` folder just use 
`echo base_path();`

To get `FILES` folder (or whatever path you need inside the Laravel's base) use `echo base_path('FILES');`
it will output `/var/www/laravel-site/FILES`